# NSLocalizedString for a set.messagebody with strings in it

Tags: ios, swift, email, in-app, messageui

I'm translating my app right now

I have a problem with 1 line that does not translate here it is :

```
mailVC.setMessageBody(NSLocalizedString("Your Hazard Index Score : \((totalScore as NSNumber).stringValue)\n Confidential data score", comment: ""), isHTML: false)
```

I've set it up in my localized.strings but when i run the app in french it does not translate

I'm sure it is related to the .string value in there but how could i translate only the text ?

thanks !

Edit: it is very specific to that set.messagebody property for message UI

Comment: \n symbol is there in french translated string?

Comment: yes, I've copy pasted the code in the localized.strings and changed the text only